# how to set data with form input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't manage to take over input values from the selection in a calculation. What am I doing wrong?

Depending on your selection it should take over the number of the 'car' and use it for the calculation formula.

```html
<select name="car">
  <option value="9">Volvo</option>
  <option value="8">Saab</option>
  <option value="7">Fiat</option>
  <option value="6">Audi</option>
</select>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = apple.valueAsNumber + cherry.valueAsNumber + apple.valueAsNumber + cherry.valueAsNumber * car.valueAsNumber">
  <input type="number" min="0" id="apple" name="apple" value="0"></p>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="cherry" name="cherry" value="0"></p>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="car" value="0" name="car"></p>
  <output name="amount" for="cherry apple car">0</output>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you know order of operations? Is the multiplication supposed to only be on the last one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: get the value like document.getElementById('car').options[document.getElementById('car').selectedIndex].value